# Using font icons in WP8.1 Silverlight ApplicationBar

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, application-bar

I'm trying to figure out why I can't use the [glyphicons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx) that are available to WP8 XAML apps in my Silverlight 8.1 Application.

As you can see from the fragment below, I have to specify an image to use as the icon compared to the ease of using one of the glyph icons.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
```

Does anyone know how I can simply use the icons without needing to go through the extra work of creating images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WP8.1 Silverlight you need to use an image. The symbol enumeration with those glyphicons are only available for Windows (Phone) Store apps only, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx):

> **Minimum supported Phone:**  Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]